Firefox 131.0 not loading css file, but older version does
When loading a php page in Firefox 131.0 on MacOS 10.9.5 for the first time, or after clearing the browser data and cached files, Firefox doas not load the css. This is the code to load the css file in php:
<link href="https://www.somesite.com/css/latest.css" rel="stylesheet" />

And this is how the output looks in Firefox 131.0 (Desktop version) - the stylesheet is not loaded:

When loading the site in Firefox 131.0 for a second time, the css is loaded (from the browser-cached file) and everything looks good.
Now, when I load the website in an old Firefox version (v.78.15), it loads the css correctly the first time. And, strangely, when I load the site in Firefox 131.0 from my mobile, it also loads the site correctly.
I asked colleagues of mine to test this on their Desktops (all have Macs), and they find the same - the css cannot be loaded by the most recent Firefox version at first time.
Did anyone else experience the same and found a solution?
P.S. This is the website that is having the problem: https://devseqplant.org/

are there any errors in the developer tools -> console? and does the network tab show the css file has loaded?

Yes, you should check your developer tools. Also see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Did you check Firefox on a Windows PC? What OS does your mobile have? Did you test Chrome? Does your site have a CSP?

I did test in Chrome, Safari, Edge and Opera - all up-to-date versions. And in all these browsers it loads the css correctly.

I get "NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER" in Web Developer Tools > Console > Requests.

I don't have a Windows PC to test. The mobile runs iOS 16.1.1

This article could be helpful. It says there could be many causes and suggests some solutions. Obviously we cannot tell what the cause is in your case. You might be right and there could be a bug in the latest Firefox for MacOS, but it wouldn't be the most obvious cause. What happens if you access the CSS file directly?

I added the site address to my post.

I have not configured a CSP as meta element in the html. I don't know if the web server has CSP enabled. I will check this. Thanks.

When I visit the URL in your question, using Firefox 131.0.3 on Windows 11, it loads the CSS file without a problem. I do see some other problems in the console panel, but these are probably unrelated.

That would indicate it's an Mac OS Firefox 131.0-specific problem, right? The one error you probably see on line 892 is a suspected JavaScript syntax error, but the js code is correct...

As I said before, the change of this being a Mac OS Firefox 131.0-specific problem isn't all that big. It's an easy assumption to make, but not necessarily the correct one. First you should eliminate all other possible causes. It might be your network which you probably share with your colleagues. Or something you all have installed. To really test this you need a completely independent Mac with Firefox. Oh, and the suspected Javascript error is definitely real.

First thanks for checking the JS error. You are right - I have to fix this. Me and my colleagues use definitely different networks - I am on a private network in Germany, and my colleagues are on a University network in the US. I also saw this error in the console: "Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content." , which is related to  markup.js:250:53 from Firefox.

There are a lot of posts regarding this Mozilla markup.js:250:53 error. The html is being rendered before the CSS is loaded.

You can opt to have a <style>....</style> tag in your HTML page with the most important CSS rules for the layout. That will prevent the render before CSS loaded error. Also note that self-closing tags do not exist in HTML.

Thanks - I didn't know about Self-closing and Non-self-closing/Paired tags in html:o) I also checked the response time of different servers. For example, google right now had 2.44ms, stackoverflow had 14.12ms, and the website that has the css error had 172.19 response time. I guess downloading the css file to Firefox browser simply takes too long, and firefox loads the page without waiting for the css to be downloaded.

So I will find out (1) why the server response time is so long, and (2) will minify the css file, which is right now 103 KB.

Along those same lines, self-closing tags in HTML do not need and do not use a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

If https://www.devseqplant.org/css/devseq/devseq_latest_20_01.css is what's not loading for you, I can report that it loads fine on Windows with FF 131.0.3.

@Nanigashi. Thank you for the info! So it's only on Mac OS in combination with Firefox that the css file doesn't initially load. I wrote the server admin, let's see.

Unless the CSS is served from a laggy server (which should affect everyone), it doesn't really seem like it would be a server problem. I'd suggest (in no particular order) a problem with MacOS, Firefox for MacOS, something else loaded on your Macs, or a (possibly transparent) proxy between the server and your Macs. I'm not sure why any of those things would affect only one CSS file.
